# Create a year over year plot with a month x-axis via scale_x_date() with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

Consider the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

date <- seq.Date(ymd("2015-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = "day")

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 value = seq_along(date) + rnorm(length(date), sd = 100))

# Add yday and year
df$yday <- yday(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

head(df)
#         date value yday year
# 1 2015-01-01    97    1 2015
# 2 2015-01-02    89    2 2015
# 3 2015-01-03    68    3 2015
# 4 2015-01-04    57    4 2015
# 5 2015-01-05    70    5 2015
# 6 2015-01-06   100    6 2016
```

I would like to make a "year over year" plot with color assigned to year. I can do this with the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = yday, y = value, color = factor(year))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Plot]

But this results in the x-axis being "day of the year" rather than month labels. Adding `+ scale_x_date()` fails because `yday` is no longer a date.

**Is is possible to use `scale_x_date()`?**

At the end of the day, I would like to do something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, color = factor(year))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

But keep the years "stacked" on the same plot.

Comment: I take it you don't want to use the work-around given in the answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503262/using-lubridate-and-ggplot2-effectively-for-date-axis)?  Maybe clarify what's different about this, otherwise it looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this hack: We don't care what year `yday` comes from, so just convert it back to `Date` format (in which case the year will always be 1970, regardless of the actual year that a given `yday` came from) and display only the month for the x-axis labels.

You don't really need to add `yday` or `year` columns to your data frame, as you can create them on the fly in the ggplot call.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.Date(yday(date), "1970-01-01"), y = value, 
               color = factor(year(date)))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="months", date_labels="%b") +
  labs(x="Month",colour="") +
  theme_bw()
```

There's probably a cleaner way, and hopefully someone more skilled with R dates will come along and provide it.

[image]

Comment: I like it, but what do we do, if we need to compare Sep-Apr (which includes a year change). With this solution we get an ugly gap in the middle and a wrong order (Jan-Apr; Sep-Dec). Hmm....