# How to relabel x-axis

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, axes

I have a chart generated by `ggplot()` where the X-axis ranges from `1986-01-01` to `2016-12-31`.   When I display the chart, the 8000 or so values on the X axis all get jumbled up and the result looks like a solid line!

(The Y-axis ranges from 300 to about 2200, and it shows the values 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000, without any additional input from me).

How do I change this so it displays just a few years on the X-axis, like say 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 2006, 2011 and 2016?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://kbroman.org/datacarpentry_R_2016-08-23/03-ggplot2.html) side could help you to clarify your problem.

Comment: Useful [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503262/using-lubridate-and-ggplot2-effectively-for-date-axis)